# Google Cloud bigQuery connect ruby API query to table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a software product with a Ruby API that generates a table-like output when queried, and I would like to dynamically connect the output to Google Cloud bigQuery.

Having read the documentation, there is a dynamic connector for Google Sheets, and static ETL connectors to PostgreSQL and other (https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/05/bigquery-integrates-with-google-drive).

If I have a ruby query that looks like the one below:

```
ruby productX-api/ruby/query_table.rb param1 param2
```

and this produces a table from the query:

```
field1,field2,field3
foo,bar,bar
xyz,abc,def
```

What options do I have to connect this to bigQuery?

Comment: Hmm. I'm a little confused (maybe because I don't know Ruby): _"generates a table-like output when queried"_: what does this mean? Does it return a big string/file e.g. csv?

Comment: @GrahamPolley yes it's a ruby script that returns a big string/file e.g. in csv format. How can I connect this to bigQuery?

Comment: What do you mean by _"connect"_? You want to load that data into BigQuery, right?

Comment: Either have a daemon that loads it every hour or have a way of having the query connected to the bigQuery table, like it's currently available with Google Sheets.

Comment: Does the result of the ruby call truncate an existing table or is it a new table with each load?

Comment: New table with each load.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in connector as you'd like but you can pretty easily load the resulting csv file programmatically by using the [Google Cloud client library for Ruby](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-ruby/#/). For example:

```
require "google/cloud/bigquery"

bigquery = Google::Cloud::Bigquery.new
dataset = bigquery.dataset "my_dataset"
table = dataset.table "my_table"

file = File.open "my_data.csv"
load_job = table.load_job file
```

More information [here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-ruby/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.51.0/google/cloud/bigquery/table?method=load_job-instance) for the particular load_job method.